# Do different TeX distributions produce PDFs of different quality?

Tags: pdf, distributions

Let's say I have the same TeX input, do different TeX distributions produce different PDF, and if so, which would produce best quality for print? I know my Miktex uses fontconfig to some intent, would a Mac OS X TeX distribution use Quartz/Cairo font facilities for instance?

Comment: The *distributions* should not make any difference, as noted in @MartinSchröder's answer. However you *may* see differences when viewing with different PDF viewers, and on different OS platforms.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. All free distributions of TeX software (i.e. MikTeX & TeXLive) use the same software which produces the same results on all platforms.

Note that this may not be true for the few commercial distributions left (e.g. BaKoMaTeX).

Comment: What if `luatex` or `xetex` is used with system fonts? Could there be a difference in that case?

Comment: If you use different fonts, you will have results looking different.

Comment: @StephanLukasczyk: Yes, but that doesn't depend on the distribution but on the fonts. You could transfer these fonts to other platforms and would then get the same results there.

Comment: If all the distributions produce same quality of PDF, then why would the distribution require or depend on fontconfig? Since fontconfig obviously has direct relationship to font metrics, then a different version of fontconfig MAY result in a different PDF using different font metrics, thus resulting in turn in different visual?

Comment: @amn Why do you think `fontconfig` has a 'direct relationship to font metrics'? If that is true, it is certainly not obviously so, and I would like some evidence that it is true at all. As far as I know, `fontconfig` is used to find the fonts but that is all. If this were not the case, you shouldn't be able to use a font `fontconfig` doesn't know about by specifying the full path but you can. Indeed, as far as I know, Xe/LuaTeX doesn't even use the substitution rules from `fontconfig`. The metrics are in the fonts.

Comment: Sorry, not `fontconfig` but `freetype` (on Linux, for instance). PDF may either embed font outlines, reference font by name (no embedding of outlines) and provide the text to render, or convert text to outlines, essentially having a PDF viewer display text as it would display shapes etc. In at least one out of these three cases - the last one - `freetype` or another library, depending on the platform, will be involved by TeX to convert text to vector graphics. This means that this vector graphics essentially depends on which library, and, by extension platform, was used to produce it.

Answer (score 4):

Martin Schröder's answer is entirely correct. The different free distributions use the same software and so should produce the same results.

However, different *versions* of pdfTeX may produce different PDFs. This is not necessarily a matter of quality, though, and I doubt it would make much difference to the printed result. It might, however, make a difference to the size of the PDF, for example, or to its compatibility with different PDF viewers. That said, the defaults are very conservative so it is very unlikely a PDF produced by even the latest pdfTeX will not work on the vast majority of machines. In fact, this has happened to me only once on a campus which was using a really ancient version of Adobe Reader. The PDFs produced by default by pdfTeX at that time could not be viewed on the standard PCs. The PDFs produced by a sufficiently ancient version of pdfTeX would possibly have been OK. (Since it is easy to alter the version of PDF produced, I didn't pursue this line of enquiry.)

Print quality would be affected if fonts were not embedded and the document was printed on a machine which did not have fonts matching those on the machine where it was produced or which had different versions of those fonts. Again, though, all reasonably recent distributions have embedded all fonts by default, including the base 14 subset of the 35 postscript fonts (for documents using scripts which are not too large e.g. Latin, Greek etc.).

Different results might also be obtained on a machine where the local administrator had changed the default settings system-wide e.g. to use a different set of the 35 postscript fonts or to embed or not embed certain fonts. But that is not a question of the distribution of TeX in use but of the way the distribution is customised for the local environment.

Comment: That's probably the difference betweeen PDF 1.5 (with object streams) and PDF 1.4.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Actually, I think it was between 1.3 and 1.4. (pdfTeX was producing 1.4 and Adobe Reader could only cope with 1.3.) But I might be mixing up the numbers...

Comment: For 1.3 to 1.4 you would get a graceful fallback: Some colours (using transparency) would simply be wrong. But 1.5 simply won't work.

Comment: @MartinSchröder In that case, I have no idea why Adobe Reader 4 could not open PDFs generated with pdfTeX. We assumed it was because it wanted 1.3 at most and pdfTeX was generating 1.4. If that's not the case - and it was just our guess at the time - I have no idea.

Comment: That would be the case - AR 4 can only open 1.3. In theory the viewer could try it anyway, but AR probably fails safe.